# How can I list all the children of 'ul' in Selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium

**I want to get all the direct children 'li' of the 'ul'**

**restrictions**

- I can't modify the html

```
<div class='showcasegrid'>
  <ul  class='seen-element'>
    <li>
      <div>
        <li>
        </li>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul  class='seen-element'>
    <li>
      <div>
        <li>
        </li>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: This code lists all the li, I only want the direct children of ul
```    
allLi = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ShowcaseGrid')
    for i, allProducts in enumerate(allLi.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')):
        print(allProducts.text)
```

Comment: You can try by xpath targetting only direct childrens. driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='seen-element']/li")

Comment: thank you very much, solve my problem with your help